# Redirect all requests to another url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, request, webrequest

I have sip application on my iPhone. It uses sip.server.com url to send requests and get responces.

How can I redirect all request (**not only http**) from my domen to sip.server.com and then all responces from sip.server.com redirect to the application on iPhone.

So I want to write my own domen instead of sip.server.com in the iPhone application.

Is it possible with asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write a cname record for your domain pointing to sip.server.com and this should do the trick.

Comment: will it redirect non http requests? and sip requests too? if so, please provide some code

Comment: Yes it will. It will simply resolve the IP address of sip.server.com if someone requests your server irrespective of the protocol.

Comment: can you provide some code or some links to read about cname record?

Comment: cname records can be only at hosting provider side, is it so?

Comment: You need to modify them from your domain registrar or hosting provider  depending where are your zone files. One more thing you need to make sure that sip.server.com doesn't bind to a particular host name.

Comment: You can ask their support guys. They should be able to help you.

Comment: They wouldn't help me, because they are not interested in that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rewrite](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/30/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one.aspx)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirects to www.my-domain.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mydomain.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.my-domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: will it redirect non http requests? and sip requests too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IIS Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to redirect all requests from your domain to required url.

**[Example]** [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

For Non HTTP Requests, you can use [DNS Simple](https://dnsimple.com/) to do all required redirection

Comment: How will you handle non http requests from IIS?

Comment: will it redirect non http requests? and sip requests too?

Comment: @ApurvGupta I agree that there is a need to write a CNAME record to point to required url. To my knowledge all types of redirections can be done using DNSimple https://dnsimple.com/ Do you know any other ways of doing this?

Comment: @Ahmed I guess DNSimple will do the same i.e. writing a cname for you. You can write a cname record wherever your zone file is.